# How can I get colored output with printf in a Perl CGI program?

Tags: perl

I want to set font color and style for what I need to print in a Perl CGI program.

We are not using CPAN.txt file to install module use `Term::ANSIColor` and all.

Example:

```
print "Hello world";
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html

Answer (score 2):

**CGI Related Answer** *(when the question was modified to be for CGI)*

If you want to achieve colour on a webpage, then you do this by [CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html).

In your html markup you can apply direct markup to set font style, size and color:

```
<span style="font-size: 1.5em; color: #555555; font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Hello World</span>
```

It is recommended to separate your CSS from your markup and instead use CSS style attributes.

```
...
<head>
    <style>
        .hello { 
             font-size: 1.5em;
             color: #555555;
             font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
         }
    <style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div><span class="hello">Hello World</span></div>
 ...
```

In this way, the CSS *class* can be reused elswhere in your HTML markup.

You can also put all the CSS into it's own CSS file (example `my.css`):

```
.hello { 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #555555;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

And then `<link>` that in your outputted HTML:

```
...
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div><span class="hello">Hello World</span></div>
 ...
```

When it comes to utilizing perl, then you are best approaching the problem by utilizing [templating](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/08/21/templating.html). Put your HTML into a template file, load the template in via something such as `HTML::Template` or `Template::Toolkit`, populate any values you require and then output your HTML page from that template.

This allows you to seperate the "markup/html" away from your programming logic, avoids the messiness of inline here documents and makes future maintenance of your code easier.

If you have "dynamic" colour for your output (colors that may change on a page), define each as a class, and use the templating to set which class to use to utilize to give the chosen style.

**Original Question Answer**
*(when it appeared that the output was to a terminal)*

Termcap can provide color (depending on the `TERM` set in your environment).

You can utilize termcap via the `Term::ScreenColor` CPAN module:

```
 use Term::ScreenColor;

 my $term = new Term::ScreenColor();
 $term->green->puts('This is green')->reset();
```

I do not recommend `Term::ANSIColor`, as it just issues raw ANSI colour sequences, and does not recognise your term environment. (If you run code using `Term::ANSIColor` on a term without colour you end up with `[34;2m` type sequences in your output).

Note: this module has dependency on `Term::Screen` which in turn requires `Term::Cap`.

Comment: Thanks for exaplaining why `Term::ANSIColor` is deprecated

Comment: if we are not using CPAN module then how can i give color module in cgi file?

Comment: If your output is to "cgi" (I.e a webpage) then ansi color sequences will not work, you should rather be researching CSS - maybe http://search.cpan.org/dist/CSS/CSS.pm (although that's more CPAN modules :)

Comment: You can easily do colour in CGIs, but that is better done through [templating](http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/08/21/templating.html). There you have a webpage "template" which contains the CSS to give your webpage colour.

Comment: @JitenderBandari you should have specified that in your question that you want it to be colored in a cgi file

Comment: @JohnDoe yup changed the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: @DravSloan: Tried `Term::ScreenColor` on some terminals. Observed that it doesn't work on `Guake`.

Comment: `Term::ScreenColor` is very sensitive to both your `TERM` environment setting *and* what is in the systems `termcap(5)`.  Note on some distributions this is provided by `terminfo(5)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Answering as per the updated question. [Drav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141633/257635) has already shown you how to print colored output in terminal.

For printing colored information in browser just use CSS. Edit your HTML/Template file to include relative HTML tags and stylesheet.

If you want to provide style data from your CGI script then you can do something like below

```
print h1({-style=>'Color: red;'},'Hello world');
```

Also: Please read the [CGI documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) first before asking such basic questions.